# LESS in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, less

How do I use LESS in CodeIgniter? I found a LESS compiler for PHP (lessphp), but could not get it to work in CodeIgniter.

My goal is to make the project have a customizable interface where the User can change the colors, etc..

Has anyone done this?

Comment: You can use LESS in Codeigniter like in any other website/application..

Comment: @Hardy Okay, but you know some library already implemented in CodeIgniter?

Comment: I found. [Here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/164741/P15)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have done this with assets folder you can check out my repo on [github](https://github.com/Shaz3e/S3-CodeIgniter-Assets/) maybe you can learn from this or if you can share your codes here maybe I can help you with it.